# filter function not working in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble getting the filter function to work in R, and I can't figure out why. I'm working through an example in the Kleiber and Zeileis (2008) 'Applied Econometrics with R' book as below:

```
data("UKDriverDeaths")
lines(filter(UKDriverDeaths, c(1/2, rep(1, 11), 1/2)/12), col = 2)
```

In R Studio 0.99.486 it gives me the error:

```
Error in lines(filter(UKDriverDeaths, c(1/2, rep(1, 11), 1/2)/12), col = 2) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function      'lines': Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "ts"
```

And in R 3.2.2 it gives me the error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

I usually use R Studio so not sure if the 'plot.new' error is due to something I don't understand about R 3.2.2, however for the R Studio error I can't understand why the error says 'no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "ts"' as the filter function is specifically for time series.

Is this something to do with the version of R Studio I'm using?

I would be grateful for any advice as it's driving me a bit crazy.

Comment: I'm guessing you might have another package loaded that's overloading filter.  Try `stats::filter`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: A likely culprit: `dplyr::filter` masks `stats::filter` if `dplyr` is loaded. Thus the messages when it loads.

Answer (score 4):

`dplyr::filter` is masking `stats::filter` (the one you're trying to use).

You can tell this is the case because the function `dplyr::filter` internally calls the function `dplyr::filter_` (**note the final underscore**), and the error you have is with `dplyr::filter_`, if you look at the [traceback](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/traceback.html).

Comment: FWIW, I realize that others already answered this properly, but they answered within comments underneath the original post.  I wanted to provide an actual answer, for the next person who runs across this question.